# App crashing when scrolling UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am creating table cells in a table view they load correctly and you can scroll down them fine but if you scroll back up the app crashes with the error `fatal error: Index out of range`

This is the code producing the table cells

Im quite new to coding in swift so please be clear on your answers

```
 public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return(tableRows.count)
    }

    var howmanyindex = 0

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ReviewControllerTableViewCell
        cell.label1.text = profilerComments[tableRows[howmanyindex]]
        cell.label2.text = String(profilerRatings[tableRows[howmanyindex]])
        howmanyindex += 1

        return(cell)
    }
```

Comment: Dont handle index manually. you will have to then worry about direction of scroll and all and hence the crash is happening because when you scroll up your index should reduce which is not happening. Use indexpath.row directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be with `howmanyindex`. Since you are using reusable cells, `cellForRowAt` is going to get called several times for a cell at a certain position if a cell goes out of the visible part of the screen.

Just use `indexPath.row` to index your data source array.

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ReviewControllerTableViewCell
    cell.label1.text = profilerComments[tableRows[indexPath.row]]
    cell.label2.text = String(profilerRatings[tableRows[indexPath.row]])
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When tableView scrolls your `howmanyindex += 1`is increasing for every visible cells hence index going beyond your  tableRows array, its better you use `indexpath.row` of tableRows.

Answer (score 2):

No need to keep tracking the index of the table manually `howmanyindex` because it may be different from your data(or returning count) so when you fetch the data from your array it may come nil from the array and you **got crashed**.

**So you can get the current cell index from** `indexPath.row`

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ReviewControllerTableViewCell
        cell.label1.text = profilerComments[tableRows[indexPath.row]]
        cell.label2.text = String(profilerRatings[tableRows[indexPath.row]])

        return(cell)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
cell.label1.text = profilerComments[tableRows[indexpath.row]]
```

in place of

```
cell.label1.text = profilerComments[tableRows[howmanyindex]]
```